# ng-repeat hide a property if its equals DateTime.MinValue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im trying to  *hide cells* (not the complete row) containg a date that is equal to `DateTime.MinValue` which is basically `0001-01-01T00:00:00`.

Here is my view model:

```
$scope.vm.users = [
    {
        "Username": "user1",
        "EarliestLogin": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "LatestLogin": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "Username": "user2",
        "EarliestLogin": "2016-07-15T11:18:19Z",
        "LatestLogin": "2016-07-15T11:18:19Z"
    },
    {
        "Username": "user3",
        "EarliestLogin": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "LatestLogin": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
];
```

The table looks like that:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Earliest Login</th>
      <th>Latest Login</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
      <td>{{user.Username}}</td>
      <td>{{user.EarliestLogin | date:'short'}}</td>
      <td>{{user.LatestLogin | date:'short'}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Current Output:**

```
User Name   Earliest Login  Latest Login
user1   1/1/01 12:00 AM 1/1/01 12:00 AM
user2   7/15/16 1:18 PM 7/15/16 1:18 PM
user3   1/1/01 12:00 AM 1/1/01 12:00 AM
```

**Desired Output:**

```
User Name   Earliest Login  Latest Login
user1   
user2   7/15/16 1:18 PM 7/15/16 1:18 PM
user3
```

---

I was able to hide the complete row using a filter on the `ng-repeat` but I don't know how to only hide a cell if its `DateTime.MinValue`...

Here is my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lLRpvKzHs9d3V4W4D6Fh?p=preview).

Comment: martin i am  unable to understand one thing,do  you want to check with Earliest Login with   Latest Login or Earliest Login with DateTime.MinValue??

Comment: @SaE Sorry, should had clarified that more. I want to hide each Earliest Login that is equal to `0001-01-01T00:00:00`, same with the Latest Login but still show the User Name

Comment: have you tried with ng-if or ng-show as one of our mate mentioned below??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the first glance, you can create a helper function

```
$scope.vm.isDateTimeMinValue = function (value) {
    return value === "0001-01-01T00:00:00";
};
```

And use it in your template

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
    <td>{{user.Username}}</td>
    <td><span ng-hide="vm.isDateTimeMinValue(user.EarliestLogin)">{{user.EarliestLogin | date:'short'}}</span></td>
    <td><span ng-hide="vm.isDateTimeMinValue(user.LatestLogin)">{{user.LatestLogin | date:'short'}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A0fkY53eVxta8HUMGZzI?p=preview)

**Note!** You can define `"0001-01-01T00:00:00"` as an [Angular JS constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) using the corresponding service.

Comment: just you have the Z options (0001-01-01T00:00:00Z) so maybe indexOf..

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-if` with the condition on a `span` tag inside `td` cell, Taking that `$scope.DateTime.MinValue` is a cope variable with the minimum value that you require:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
   <td>{{user.Username}}</td>
   <td><span ng-if="$scope.DateTime.MinValue != user.EarliestLogin">{{user.EarliestLogin | date:'short'}}</span></td>
   <td><span ng-if="$scope.DateTime.MinValue != user.LatestLogin ">{{user.LatestLogin | date:'short'}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: There is no `DateTime.MinValue` in JavaScript. More over, if it's supposed to use a string constant in a template, it's not a good choice.

Comment: yeah thats not there, i expected it to be a scope variable, and in your case the issue is the '<td>' will hide away. If only one value matches , like wise if EarliestLogin matches and LatestLogin  doesn't, the structure of the table will be wrecked.